# Verilog handling input wires

Tags: verilog

I am learning Verilog, so please understand my lack of knowledge. I have a module with input as follows:

```
input   FIRE_IN;
```

I want to drive this input high and low. For example,

```
reg [31:0] counter;

always @(posedge CLK) begin counter <= counter + 1; end

assign "something to drive FIRE_IN" = counter[10];
```

I am looking for a way to tie an output pin to an input pin through software.

Comment: Please explain more details. What do you mean by "I am looking for a way to tie an output pin to an input pin through software."?

Answer (score 1):

If something is considered an input at a local scope, then you cannot assign it.

With digital logic there must be no more than one active driver on a net at any given time. When a signal is marked as an input, it means it's driver is external to the current scope. If the signal is an output, it means it's driver is internal to the currents scope (same level or sub-module). If the signal is an inout, then a protocol must exist to ensure only one drive is active at any given time.

There will be conflict if there is ever two or more active drivers with opposing values on the same net. In simulation this will result in `X` as the signal value. On FPGA/ASIC this will create a short between power and ground (which can damage the device).

You need to figure at what scope you need the an expression combining `counter[10]` and `FIRE_IN`. Create outputs to bring the value `counter[10]` up to that level. Create your intermediate logic at this level. Then connect this new logic to where `FIRE_IN` was used. This creates a feedback system.

Example:

```
module MODULENAME( output CNT10, /* ... */ );
  /* ... */
  assign CNT10 = counter[10];
  /* ... */
endmodule

module TOPMODULE( /* ... */ );
  /* ... */
  assign some_logic = func(FIRE_IN, CNT10, /* ... */ );
  MODULENAME instname( .CNT10_OUT(CNT10), .FIRE_IN(some_logic),  /* ... */ );
  /* ... */
endmodule
```

**IMPORTANT:** Keep your feedback synchronous (update on clock edge). Asynchronous feedback infer level-sensitive latches which are prone to timing issues that create glitches and unintended behavior. Keeping the feedback synchronous mitigates this risk.

Comment: Greg, I am sorry to say that I am still not getting it. I understand that if a module contains an input, it must be either driven by another module or from outside the component by a physical wire. I have read over your explanation many times and I still cannot get it.

Comment: I now understand how it works. I was making it more difficult than necessary.